# Graphical audio file tagger & renamer for Linux?

Tags: linux, open-source, audio, gui, metadata-editor

What's a good utility for tagging and renaming audio files (m4a, mp3, aac etc.), on Linux, using a GUI?

Requirements:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Supports at least a bit of automation (e.g. renaming using a filename pattern)

Desired features:

- Small
- Loads quickly
- Doesn't have a lot of dependencies (e.g. won't drag half of GNOME or KDE)

Answer (score 1):

#### EasyTag

[image]

Website: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG

Basic features:

- Written in C using GTK 3, part of the GNOME project
- Source: Open source, see website or the [Gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/easytag/)
- License: GNU GPL v2
- Supported audio formats: MP3, MP2, MP4/AAC, FLAC, Ogg Opus, Ogg Speex, Ogg Vorbis, MusePack, Monkey's Audio, and WavPack
- Platforms: GNU/Linux, MS Windows

Some automation features:

- Autocomplete
- Scan and add data automatically from databases like FreeDB and GnuDB.
- Auto tagging by fields using masks/templates
- Rename files and directories using file tags, using masks
- Field processing (uppercasing, lowercasing etc.)
- Action undo capability

etc.